# django-admin custom command giving settings error

Tags: django

this is my setupproject.py custom command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print 111111111111111
```

When I execute it as `django-admin setupproject` I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`./manage.py setupproject` I think.
Also maybe you have some incorrect properties in your settings.py

Comment: I want it to be run without the project, so manage is not there yet

Comment: Without the project? Can you explain in details and update the question? Maybe I misunderstood the your question =)